# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning Cast error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm stuck with an error using mongoose and mongodb that won't let me locate things in my database beause of cast errors.

I have a user schema

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, min: 1, required: true }
});

export default mongoose.model('user',schema);
```

in another file I have this where the user_id gets input from an input field

```
User.findOne({ name: user_id })
  .then(user => {
    if(user) {
      console.log("found user");
      console.log(user);
    } else {
      console.log("user not found");
    }
  })
});
```

The problem is that I get the cast error, also in the error I can see the value of user_id is getting the correct value, i.e 'testing', name of user in database i'm inputting from input field.

```
(node:1127) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ user_id: 'testing' }" at path "name" for model "user"
```

If I change the first line of code to

```
User.findOne({})
```

The query finds one and prints out

```
{ _id: 5a952b07327915e625aa0fee, name: 'testing' }
```

but if I change the code to either

```
User.findOne({ name: user_id })
```

and enter in the search box 'testing', or

```
User.findOne({ _id: user_id })
```

and then enter in the id '5a952b07327915e625aa0fee', I get the error. I also get a similar error when using

```
User.findById(user_id)
node:1166) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ user_id: '5a952adf327915e625aa0fed' }" at path "_id" for model "user"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
User.findById('5a952adf327915e625aa0fed')
    .then(user => console.log(user))  // user can be undefined
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

or

```
User.findOne({name: 'testing'})
    .then(user => console.log(user))  // user can be undefined
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Comment: It works if I put the actual id in the findById query but not if I pass it in, is it something to do with how i'm passing the data then?

Comment: As far as I see from your error log, you try to invoke the `findById` with an object. Try to invoke with a `String`.

Comment: Yes that worked thanks, I was assuming what I was passing in the string, i.e user_id but it was the actual object of the user not the value. Changed to `findById(user_id.user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
User.findOne({ name: user_id })
  .then(user => {
    if(user) {
      console.log("found user");
      console.log(user);
    } else {
      console.log("user not found");
    }
}).catch(err => console.log("something went wrong");)
```